# WAMP suddenly went offline, won't go back online

Tags: windows-10, wampserver, port80

I've been using WAMP server on my Windows 10 PC without a hitch, and WAMP suddenly went down earlier today and won't go back online, even after rebooting the PC.

If I test Port 80 from Apache, it tells me

> Your port 80 is not actually used.

however, the httpd.conf tells me

> Listen 12.34.56.78:80 Listen 0.0.0.0:80 Listen [::0]:80

...so presumably it does use Port 80 ??

I don't have Internet Information Services, or World Wide Web Publishing Service, or Web Deployment Agent Service, or Skype running on the PC (stopping these is a solution I've seen elsewhere) - so that's not the issue.

Running `netstat -aon | findstr :80` via command line gives me a PID of 4500 but this isn't listed in the task manager - so I can't figure out what the issue is here.

Any ideas?

I'm loath to change the port used by WAMP as it was working fine until a few hours ago, but is this my only option?

Comment: Just tried changing from port 80 to 7080 in the Apache http.conf file but WAMP still offline :-\

Answer (score 0):

Ahhhh - problem solved! I had inadvertently renamed the www folder. All good after changing it back again.